# Не получается спарсить dotabuff

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Написал код, который должен парсить страницу игроков на dotabuff и затем возвращать всю нужную мне информацию, но вместо полной html страницы я получаю

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>DOTABUFF - Too Many Requests</title>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<style>
    html {
      background: #1C242D;
      color: #C4C4C4;
      font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      margin: 21% auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
    p a {
      color: #A9CF54;
      text-decoration: none
    }
    #logo {
      background: #ED3B1C;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-weight: 800;
      padding: 6px 12px;
    }
    #logo a {
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    #status {
      font-weight: 200;
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="logo"><a href="/">DOTABUFF</a></h1>
<h2 id="status">Too Many Requests</h2>
<p>You have been rate limited for making too many requests. Please try again later.</p>
<p><a href="/">Home</a> | <a href="/pages/about#support">Support</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

вот пример кода для `team = TeamSpirit`, `player = Yatoro`

```
def get_winrate(team, player, hero):
    url = f'https://www.dotabuff.com/search?q={team.replace(" ", "+")}+{player.replace(" ", "+")}&commit=Search'
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
    print(soup)
```

Comment: В html ответе же написано: "You have been rate limited for making too many requests. Please try again later.". Значит слишком много запросов шлете, пробуйте позже.

Comment: это сообщение я получаю каждый раз, когда пытаюсь спарсить, не важно какой интервал я делаю. Даже в первую попытку спарсить я получил это же.

Comment: Ну значит как минимум нужно клиент в заголовке запроса менять, чтобы requests не палился

Comment: можете скинуть ссылку на статью, как это сделать?

Comment: Ну, вот например https://www.zenrows.com/blog/python-requests-user-agent

Comment: похоже что антифрод палит Ваш парсер. Либо сам requests из коробки шлет несколько запросов вряд. постоянно ловля ошибку, затем, когда лимит исчерпан, то получает этот html. Могу написать парсер по вашему запросу, опыт большой в парсинге. Тут индивидуально смотреть и пробовать разных подходы нужно. tg: @default_user2  

Скорее всего, так как это не SPA, а классика, тут скорее всего нужно поиграть с заголовками запросов, как это рекомендавал Николай Бердников Для этого нужно в инспекторе браузера посмотреть с какими заголовками улетает запрос и имитировать эти заголовки в коде python.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `selenium`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://ru.dotabuff.com/players')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0'}
response = requests.get('https://ru.dotabuff.com/search?q=TSpirit.Yatoro&commit=Search', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.text)
```